# Carousel with recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, carousel

I'm trying to make this carousel work with a recursive function. Let's say I have three classes defined on CSS with transitions attached to them (default, onscreen, offscreen). The idea is I call images from default adding a dynamic class on them and send them offscreen and the back on queue. The number of images is 4. The carousel was working until I added the conditional statement needed for keeping the carousel running forever.

I call the function of moveKitties with index 0 and somehow the function doesn´t keep invoking itself after 0. Any idea what's wrong in it?

```
(function() {

    var kitty = document.querySelectorAll(".kitty-container img");
      
    function moveKitties(n) {
        kitty[n].classList.remove("onscreen");
        kitty[n].classList.add("offscreen");
        if (n === 3) {
            kitty[0].classList.add("onscreen");
            setTimeout(function () {
                moveKitties(0);
            }, 3000);
        } else {
            kitty[n+1].classList.add("onscreen");
            setTimeout(function () {
                moveKitties(n);
            }, 3000);
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("transitionend", function(e) {
        if (e.target.style.right == 0) {
            // console.log(e);
            e.target.classList.remove("offscreen");
        }
    });

    
    setTimeout(moveKitties(0), 3000);
})();
```

Comment: Should `moveKitties(n);` be `moveKitties(n+1);`?

Comment: No, I don't think that's the problem. With n+1 I'm calling the next image to be "onscreen" and the function starts removing the image from "onscreen"

Comment: Yep - but you need to change the value of `n` somehow for the next iteration of moveKitties(), otherwise it will stay as the `0` set by the setTimeout() call at the end of the code.

Comment: Yeah, true. You are right. How  couldn't see it.... :S

Comment: So, if you change it to `n+1` does it work ok now?

Comment: Yep, somehow, but it's funny because it's working somehow only after some loops. In the beginning images are kind of flying around until it "stabilises" with a normal flow. Thanks btw

Comment: Ok - without the rest of the code, html and css, I can't say what could be causing that.  Check that each of the img items has the right css class name to start with.  It looks like you should have three classes - onscreen, offscreen and something else (perhaps, "hidden" or something like that) and the last one should be the initial state, so they move from "hidden" to "onscreen" to "offscreen" and back to "hidden"?

Comment: yeah no worries, I'm going to check everything. My main concern was the recursion, thank you!

Comment: Ok - np.  Use the "Inspect element" option of your browser and watch what happens to each item as that should help identify what needs to be tweaked

Comment: I could finally figure out the problem. When I am adding the event listener of "transitionends" I get two e.target, the one transitioning from the right and the one transitioning to the left. So I am basically removing the "offscreen" to both elements. No idea how to solve this till now